# Почему не переопределяется переменная в подклассе

Tags: java, наследование

Пытаюсь для класса Car задать свое значение переменной type и чтобы оно выводилось при вызове у класса метода getType(). Но при попытке переназначить эту переменную с новым значением - она не переназначается, и выводится значение type из главного класса Vehicle.

```
package Day20AprilTasks;

public class Vehicle {
  **  static String type = "Common";**
    static String producer = "MechDevelop";
    double weight = 0;
    double length = 0;
    String name = "no";


    public void setName(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }
    public void getName(){
        System.out.println("Name is "+ this.name);
    }

    public static void setProducer(){
        System.out.println("Producer is "+ producer);
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setLength(double length){
        this.length = length;
    }

**
 public static void getType(){
        System.out.println("Type of machine is "+ type);
**
    }
    public static void getProducer(){
        System.out.println("Producer is "+ producer);
    }

}

package Day20AprilTasks;

public class Car extends Vehicle{

   ** static String type = "Car"; **
    
}


ackage Day20AprilTasks;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Car.getType();

    }
}
```

Вывод: Type of machine is Common

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Потому что она у вас статичная

Comment: Статические поля/методы не переопределяются.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что я не могу наследовать статичные методы и переменные в java?

Comment: Всем спасибо, в таком случае придется вызывать метод только через объект.

Comment: @Oleg Правильно понимаете) Вы можете вызвать поле через класс: `Vehicle.type;`

Comment: @Митяй. Тогда еще вопросец: почему я могу вызвать метод getProducer для класса Car? он ведь тоже статичный. Резюмируя:  я могу наследовать статичные методы и переменные, но не могу их переопределять в подклассе, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Oleg Статические методы/поля в Java наследуются, но не могут быть переопределены. Если вы объявляете один и тот же метод в подклассе, вы скрываете метод суперкласса вместо того, чтобы переопределять его. Да, вы правильно поняли!

Comment: Ура, спасибо!!!)

Comment: @Митяй сидел я тыкался и пришел к тому, что мы вообще не можем переназначать переменные. даже не статичные) изменение их в подклассе не работает...
Основная проблема - это то, что все методы, которые я использую в подклассах, используют переменные из родительского класса.